# Can't achieve to beat a ball in my JS Pong Game

Tags: javascript, canvas, pong

I've written a simple pong game in JS,but i can't force ball to change it direction while it touches a paddle.Below i've inserted my actual beatControl funtcion.

```
function beatControl() {

if (ballX + ballSize >= xAiPosition) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    //console.log(ballX);
} else if (ballX == xPosition + paddleWidth) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    // console.log(ballX);
}
```

}

[Here's the link to my game](https://jsfiddle.net/2hts8cqj/)

Comment: Just a recommendation, you should look into using objects for your game. You would have a paddle object and a ball object, it's much more manageable and as you make more complex things objects will really come in handy. Check the source code of this project for an example using objects - http://betaio.bitballoon.com/

Comment: Thank you Jared,it's my first project so probably it does not look professional :)

Comment: Yeah, that pong game was actually the first game I created too. If you want any advice feel free to message me on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example collision I have used in a JS pong game that I made. First it checks if it is far enough to the right or to the left, and if that is true then it checks if the paddle is also within the proper Y value to hit the ball. You can review my source code here - http://pongio.bitballoon.com/

```
    //Ball hits left paddle
    if (ball.x<=paddleLeft.width+ball.r && ball.y>=paddleLeft.y && ball.y<=paddleLeft.y+paddleLeft.height) {
        ball.velX = -ball.velX;
    }
    //Ball hits right paddle
    else if (ball.x>=canvas.width-(paddleLeft.width+ball.r) && ball.y>=paddleRight.y && ball.y<=paddleRight.y+paddleRight.height) {
        ball.velX = -ball.velX;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ball is bouncing off the wrong end of the paddle.

The problem is this line

```
else if (ballX == xPosition + paddleWidth)
```

Should be

```
else if (ballX <= xPosition + paddleWidth)
```

Comment: Thank You but right now ball is bouncing off the whole line which meet the condition you've posted,not only the paddle